# visual studio profiling performance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, profiling, performance-testing

My C++ program runs perfectly in release and debug mode. However, when I try to profile my code using Visual studio 2010 performance analysis. My program starts up but immediately gives the following error:

The procedure entry point ?minimumSizeHint@QcheckBox@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library QtGuid4.dll.

I find it strange that it has problems with the dll whereas in release+debug it works perfectly.
Has anyone an idea what this could be?

Comment: Very likely to be a DLL Hell problem, getting the wrong version of QtGui4.dll loaded.  QtGuid4???

Comment: It mentions QtGui4.dll and I'm running it in release mode so that should be ok. But dont get it because it works perfectly in release and debug mode so is VS performance analysis even another mode for which you have to set all the settings correctly?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Qt compatibility report](http://upstream-tracker.org/compat_reports/qt/4.7.4_to_4.8.0/abi_compat_report.html), the function QcheckBox::minimumSizeHint was added between 4.7.4 and 4.8.0.

Most likely somehow part of your DLLs are 4.8.x while QtGui is 4.7.x.